# Diffrent session in multiple browser tabs in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

So i have page that contain print button. when the user press the print button  it should open 3 new windows contain 3 report same data but different in one parameter is 'copy to' that i change every time in loop

I success with open 3 tab but all the windows contain same 'copy to'

i send the data of the report in session  to report viwer ,
 every time i change the data table to different 'copy to' through the loop .my Main problem is  its always take the last datatable

any helpplz

Comment: you need to set `datatable.AcceptChange()` for accepting the latest change.

Comment: last database ?? pls update your question with your code so that we can have a look and figure out at the issue

Comment: I mean last data table